# IBM Tree Huggers Commercial

Tags: listening

I'm trying to write down this IBM TV commercial.
Would you please help me complete it?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSNFE6eUjfY

------------ your green proposal.

Great.

It's fine, just fine.
I'm sure it'll make people feel real good about the company,
should go over --- with the tree huggers, too.
--- the folks that I report to, --------------.
Let me ask you.
Why would I sign this?

This plan could cut our energy costs by 40%.

40%.

And we spent 18 million dollars on energy last year.

Where do I sign?

Just sign here.

**Remark**

This is an American TV commercial made by IBM, which means that almost all educated native American English speakers are supposed to understand this well.
I understand most American TV commercials well.
However, I don't understand some parts of this one. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: Why are you transcribing this? For comprehension or what?

Comment: @JMB To improve my listening skill. I thought it's obvious.

Comment: The man in the commercial mumbles and speaks very quickly; even a native speaker must listen closely to catch the words at a few points.

Comment: I think the point is to portray a typical corp middle manager. Haven't seen that ad in a while.  Would be interesting to know: Why that video?

Comment: @MakotoKato, you're asking us to help you write down what was said in the commercial.  That is the definition of transcription:  "the act or process of making a written, printed, or typed copy of words that have been spoken" ([m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transcription)).  I sympathize with your problem, really, but I don't believe that transcription requests are a good fit for the ELL / ELU / StackExchange model.  (See my reasoning at http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/exactly-why-is-this-question-off-topic-or-not/5369#5369 )

Comment: (Apologies as well if I come across here or in the linked meta-answer as rude; I do hope you figure it out, and wish you good luck in your quest for improvement.)

Comment: @Hellion You wrote in the meta "*Also, the question is completely unhelpful to any other person besides the original asker."*
I disagree. I think many non-native English speakers find my question useful.

Comment: @Hellion "*you're asking us to help you write down what was said in the commercial. That is the definition of transcription:*"
I wrote down most of the commercial.
Asking for a help to write down only a part of a few sentences which you cannot comprehend
is not the same thing as asking for a transcription service in the usual sense.

Comment: It would help if you added to your question what you *think* was said. Then the specific differences could be examined, rather than reciting what was said.

Comment: @user3169 I wrote down most of the commercial which I think was said.
The rest is what I have no idea about.

Comment: I believe many non-native English speakers find this question useful.
I feel it is sad that some native English speakers think this should be closed.

Comment: I wonder why Nathan Tuggy edited my edit to the question.

Comment: I listened to it again and there are sounds where you have the blanks. Even if I did not know any English I could at least say what the unknown words sound like. Not knowing what the actual words are is OK, that is the next step.

Comment: You are asking us to **prooflisten** what you heard. This is analogous to *proofreading ("are there any mistakes?")*, which is off topic, *unless the source of concern is clearly specified*.

Comment: @user3169 I said I had no idea. Believe me. Maybe you don't understand this because you are a **native** English speaker.

Comment: @GoDucks "*What is at issue is the activity of proofreading and how prooflistening is parallel to it.*"
There is at least one thing very different between them. Let me know if you don't know it.

Comment: No. In one's native language the process of understanding is already accomplished, but the listening process is the same. To turn this around, while learning Japanese, listening to speech there are many words I do not know. But I know the sound(s) that I hear, and that is the starting point to figuring out what a word is and what it means.

Comment: @user3169 Then why I was not able to figure out some of the man's words, which were actually very basic?

Comment: If you compare the speech patterns, the man runs some words together, while the woman enunciates her words clearly. Knowing what works in context sometimes helps if listening alone is unclear. Even for me the "granola" phrase is difficult to make out. The speaking styles probably have something to do with what the advertiser is trying to portray.

Comment: @user3169 Yeah, sure. I know that.
That seems to contradict your previous comment. Care to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I've been looking over** your green proposal.

Great.

It's fine, just fine. I'm sure it'll make people feel real good about the company, should go over **big** with the tree huggers, too. **See**, the folks that I report to, **they don't eat granola**. **So** let me ask you. Why would I sign this?

This plan could cut our energy costs by 40%.

40%.

And we spent 18 million dollars on energy last year.

Where do I sign?

Just sign...

Comment: I think the last ling is "Just sign right.."

Comment: I agree with Kevin.  She says "Just sign right..." and points to the paper.  She means to say "Just sign right there."  But she's a bit nervous, so she stops in mid-sentence because she's not quite sure whether it's ok to tell her boss what to do.